# logarithmic differentiation issue

Tags: derivatives, logarithms, implicit-differentiation

Trying to understand a solution I was given to a problem I was told to use logarithmic differentiation on. $$ 1/x(x+1)(x+2) $$

and I know that $$log((ab)/c) = log(a) + log(b) - log(c)$$ So I tried to use that rule here and did: $$ln(a) - ln(b) - ln(c)$$
and got: $$ln(1) - ln(x(x+1)- ln(x(x+2)$$
which simplifies to: $$0 - ln(x^2+x)- ln(x^2+2x)$$

and then I look at the solution which gives:
$$y`=(1/(x(x+1)(x+2))) * (1/x + 1/(x+1) + 1/(x+2))$$

I'm just kind of confused on what I am doing wrong.

Comment: $ln(1)-ln(x(x+1))-ln(x(x+2)) = ln(\frac{1}{x(x+1)x(x+2)}) = ln(\frac{1}{x^2(x+1)(x+2)}) \neq ln(\frac{1}{x(x+1)(x+2)})$. Just use that $-ln(a) = ln(\frac{1}{a})$ and $ln(ab) = ln(a) + ln(b)$.

Comment: So are you saying my process is wrong?

Comment: Yes, just see you have $x^2$ while it is $x$

Comment: Right, my question is what I'm doing wrong. So I know this makes sense to you, but it doesn't to me. I'm trying to see if my process was right in that using logarithmic properties that $$ln(ab/c) = ln(a) + ln(b) - ln(c)$$. I am asking if by doing $$ln(a) - ln(b) - ln(c)$$ was correct, and if not, what is the correct procedure to do with this kind of problem.

Comment: Let's say you use $ln(a/bc) = ln(a) - ln(b) - ln(c)$. What do you take as $b$ and $c$ such that $bc = x(x+1)(x+2)$ ? Here you chose $b = x(x+1)$ and $c = x(x+2)$ but then $bc = x^2(x+1)(x+2)$ and not $x(x+1)(x+2)$

Comment: because you're multiplying x by 2 different things? I guess this is where I am confused. But was I right that I would use ln(a) - ln(b) - ln(c)? so then is b = x(x+1) and c = (x+2) ?? also is ln(a) - ln(b)- ln(c) correct?

Comment: No, it's just that if $a = \alpha \beta$ and $b = \alpha \gamma$ then $ab = \alpha \alpha \beta \gamma = \alpha^2 \beta \gamma$. Then if you call $y = \frac{1}{x(x+1)(x+2)}$ you have $\ln|y| = -(\ln|x| + \ln|x+1| + \ln|x+2|)$ and after differentiating : $\frac{y'}{y} = - (\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x+1} + \frac{1}{x+2})$. Finally, multiply by $y$ to get $y'$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have that

$$\ln f(x)=\ln \frac{1}{x(x+1)(x+2)}=\ln 1-ln x- \ln (x+1)-\ln(x+2)$$ $$=-ln x- \ln (x+1)-\ln(x+2).$$

Taking derivatives:

$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=-\frac 1x-\frac{1}{x+1}-\frac{1}{x+2}.$$ Thus

$$f'(x)=\frac{-1}{x(x+1)(x+2)}\left(\frac 1x+\frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{1}{x+2}\right).$$

**Note** a difference in sign with your expected answer.

Comment: Ohhh wait I think I get it now. using logarithmic differentation we get $$-lnx-ln(x+1)-ln(x+2)$$ and then using logarithmic properties $$ln x = 1/x$$ and we apply it all 3. and then times by original y. The only thing I'm still confused on though is how the negatives become positives in the final result.

Comment: Logarithmic differentiation is used to simplify differentiation in some cases. Note that we take logarithms to convert the quotient $1/x(x+1)(x+2)$ into a sum $-\ln x-\ln(x+1)-\ln(x+2).$ The derivative of this expression is easier. But note that derivative of this expression is $f'(x)/f(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\ln f(x).$ From this you get $f'(x).$

Comment: The minus sign doesn't become positive. There is a mistake in the solution you are given.

Comment: No I mean when you go from  $$-1/x - 1/x+1 - 1/x+2$$ to $$−1x(x+1)(x+2)(1x+1x+1+1x+2).$$

Comment: Oh sorry. Note that I have written $\frac{\bf{-1}}{x(x+1)(x+2)}.$ There it is the minus sign.

Comment: So the first one is y` and the second one is original? I guess I got confused becuase you wrote the original differently, and a lot like the one we just got $$(-1/x - 1/(x+1) - 1/(x+2) )$$ but as long as I'm understanding that your answer is simply written $$y`(y)$$ then I understand.